# Shift Function and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\in C_b(\Bbb{R})$ and be $K\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ compact. Assume that for some $t\in\Bbb{R}_+$ one has:
$$\sup_{x\in K}{|f(x+t)-f(x)|}<\varepsilon$$
I want to show the following: we can find $\delta>0$ such that the following holds: if $|s-t|<\delta$, then $\sup_{x\in K}{|f(x+s)-f(x)|}<\varepsilon$. I think that one has to choose $\delta=\varepsilon/4$ or something else or argue by contrary: Suppose not, then for all $\delta>0$ we can find $s\in\mathbb{R}_+$ with the property that $|s-t|<\delta$ implies $\sup_{x\in K}{|f(x+s)-f(x)|}\geq\varepsilon$, hence we can find a sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $t$ but $\sup_{x\in K}{|f(x+s_n)-f(x)|}\geq\varepsilon$ and the contradicts the fact that $\sup_{x\in K}{|f(x+t)-f(x)|}<\varepsilon$ holds by continuity. Is this maybe a good proof?

Comment: Yes, this is true, and you have to use the compactness of the set in question . By the way, for a first time user you have presented your question well, so a $+1$ for encouragement.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you very much. How to use compactness here since I didn't use it above?

Comment: Construct an open cover  for K as follows : take the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around each point. This has a finite subcover by compactness. Use continuity of $f$ to find a delta at the centers of the balls in the finite subcover. Take the minimum delta and see what you get. Please reply if you have not understood, but I can only be of service in the next one hour ,so if you are quick it would be better.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг : do one also has to use compactness if one argue by contradiction as I did above?

Comment: Of course, because the statement would not be true without compactness.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг :  Can you help me to use the compactness in my contradiction proof?

Comment: Sure. For this, first, you have to get the contradiction of the statement correct. I don't think you have got the contradiction statement correct, so try again, and you can either use the comments or respond in your question, because I'm viewing your question constantly for updates.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let's go with your proof idea: If false, then for each $\delta = 1/n$ there exists $s_n$ with $|s_n-t|<1/n$ such that

$$\sup_{x\in K} |f(x+s_n) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon.$$

Now for each $n$ the above $\sup$ is attained at some $x_n\in K.$ You now have a sequence $x_n$ in a compact set, so …